# Python: How to extract data in text file based on class information from another text file?

Tags: python, extract, data-extraction

In this case there are 3 classes which is represented by the value 0, 1 and 2. I would like to extract information that are belong to class 1 from another text file called fileA.txt. I would like to know how to solve this using python. 
 For example: 
**class.txt**

```
0
0
1
2
2
1
1
```

**fileA.txt**

```
a=[1,3,2,1]
b=[3,2]
c=[3,2,1]
d=[3,3]
e=[4,5,6]
f=[3,2,3]
g=[2,2]
```

**Expected output:**

```
c=[3,2,1]
f=[3,2,3]
g=[2,2]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you write a single line of code before asking?

Comment: So you want to select the same lines (by line number) from `fileA.txt` as the lines from `class.txt` what are `1`?

Comment: Yes I want to select the same lines.

Comment: You hearted my eyes dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the "class.txt" file and create list of classes:

```
with open("class.txt", "rt") as f:
    classes = [int(line) for line in f.readlines()]
```

Read the "fileA.txt" file and create list of correct lines:

```
with open("fileA.txt", "rt") as f:
    lines = [line for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()) if classes[index] == 1]
```

Show the result:

```
print "".join(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a Python solution, but I like it :)

```
$ grep -n "^1$" class.txt | cut -d: -f1 | while read linenumber
do
  sed -n "${linenumber}p" < fileA.txt
done
```

Output:

```
c=[3,2,1]
f=[3,2,3]
g=[2,2]
```

Tools used are:

- [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)
- [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)
- [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

Answer (score 1):

Here's intuitive way to do it

```
classes = [l.strip() for l in open("class.txt").readlines()]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(classes) if x == "1"]

with open('fileA.txt') as file:
    for index,line in enumerate(file):
        if(index in indices):
            print(line)
```